# Java - Closing socket when reloading class

Tags: java, sockets, port, reload

So I'm working on a server for an IRC, and I added a config screen where you can edit the port it is using, but I have to reintialize the `Listen` class for it to take effect, so I have this in my Config class:

```
Listen.closePorts();
new Listen();
```

And here is my Listen class:

```
package server.network;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import server.Server;
import server.gui.GUIMain;

public class Listen {
    private static Socket socket = null;
    private int port;

    public Listen() {
        try {
            port = Server.listenPort;
            @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
            GUIMain.jta.append("\nServer Started and listening for messages on port " + port + ".\n");

            while(true) {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                String msg = br.readLine();
                GUIMain.jta.append("Received message from client: " + msg + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            GUIMain.jta.append("Port " + port + " already in use!\n");
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            }  catch(Exception e) { }
        }
    }

    public static void closePorts() {
        try {
            socket.close();
            GUIMain.jta.append("Server closed\n");
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

When I start the application it runs this class, opening the socket with the port specified, but when I try to close the port here:

```
public static void closePorts() {
    try {
        socket.close();
        GUIMain.jta.append("Server closed\n");
    } catch (IOException e) { }
}
```

It hangs on `socket.close();`

And if I comment `Listen.closePorts();` out and try to reload the class and leaving the socket open it either hangs or runs the `catch()` if the port is the same as the port that is in use.

So long story short, How can I close the socket before reintalizing the class and use the new port?

Here's the full exception it trows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at server.network.Listen.closePorts(Listen.java:44)
    at server.gui.GUISettings.actionPerformed(GUISettings.java:86)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Are any exceptions thrown? How long does it hang for?

Comment: It's not trowing exceptions, it just hangs and after a while I just force close the application in the taskmanager

Comment: It looks like your trying to close the same socket twice? Your finally block closes the socket, and if you're calling closePorts after that it could cause issues.

Comment: Not sure, it doesn't run finally until it's done with the try or the catch block right?

Comment: No exceptions are thrown because your code is swallowing them all. Empty catch blocks are never good practice. At the very least, print the stack trace of the caught exception.

Comment: Correct. I actually have no idea if there's an adverse side effect to closing the same stream/socket twice, just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `socket` variable is not assigned until after a client makes a request. If you call `closePorts()` before that happens, your program will still be waiting at `socket = serverSocket.accept();` and `socket.close()` will throw a NullPointerException because `socket` will still be null.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept() for a description of ServerSocket.accept().

Comment: So how can I stop it from waiting for client connection?

Comment: You can call `setSoTimeout(milliseconds)` *before* `socket = serverSocket.accept()`. This will cause it to only block for a specified period of time, after which it will raise a `SocketTimeoutException`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setSoTimeout(int).

Answer (score 1):

Not providing a direct solution but no exceptions are thrown because your code is swallowing them all. Empty catch blocks are never good practice. At the very least, print the stack trace of the caught exception using e.printStackTrace()

Comment: Okay, I tried it with e.printStackTrace; It errors with a java.lang.NullPointerException, but socket is supposed to be running/waiting for a message so it can't be null right?

Comment: Can you show the full trace please? Are you able to debug around the line causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no class reloading here, and you don't need to close the existing client's accepted sockets. Just close the ServerSocket and recreate it on the new port.